# can't open file '.manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, reactjs, django, macos, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to follow this tutorial - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JD-age0BPVo&t=793s

And getting the following error.. I'm using VSC on mac

```
Sourav@Souravs-MBP Settle_Guide % python .\manage.py makemigrations
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file '.manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Sourav@Souravs-MBP Settle_Guide %
```

I made sure that I'm on the right directory while running the code. Any suggestion?

see here. https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFhRX.png

Comment: is your file called manage.py and you accidentally imported it with an extra period before the name?

Comment: yes my file is called manage.py and no there is no extra period before its name

Comment: I think you don't need to use that directory attached with command. As you are in the same directory of manage.py just run there regular command. 
`"python manage.py makemigrations"`

Comment: i did all that too..and still getting this error >>Sourav@Souravs-MBP Settle_Guide % python manage.py makemigrations             
  File "manage.py", line 17
    ) from exc
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I did find the solution though.. i needed to use python3..for some reason just python is not working for me>> Sourav@Souravs-MBP Settle_Guide % python3 manage.py makemigrations
No changes detected....thank you for the help ...i really appreciate it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This instructor is using PowerShell on Windows to enter commands. I assume you're struggling with the `.\manage.py` command underlined in this image:

[image]

On Windows, the path separator is the backslash `\`.

On Mac, the path separator is the forward slash `/`.

Also, as you discovered, the default Python interpreter on the Mac is the outdated Python 2.7. To use Python 3, you have to type `python3` instead of `python`.

Therefore, instead of `python .\manage.py`, type `python3 ./manage.py` on your Mac.

Comment: i did tried it but it gave me the following error >> Sourav@Souravs-MBP Settle_Guide % python ./manage.py makemigrations
  File "./manage.py", line 17
    ) from exc
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @SOURAVNASKAR when you input the command just do `python manage.py makemigrations`

Comment: i did all that too..and still getting this error >>Sourav@Souravs-MBP Settle_Guide % python manage.py makemigrations File "manage.py", line 17 ) from exc ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I did find the solution though.. i needed to use python3..for some reason just python is not working for me>> Sourav@Souravs-MBP Settle_Guide % python3 manage.py makemigrations
No changes detected....thank you for the help ...i really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

the error occurs when you are not in the same directory where the manage.py file is present.